# How to prevent RSelenium from closing Chrome

Tags: html, r, selenium-webdriver, rvest, rselenium

I have setup RSelenium for scrapping data from several pages. However, some pages do not exist anymore or are very slow to load, and after a while of sitting idle, Rselenium closes Chrome.

I found that one suggested solution to this in Selenium is to use detach=TRUE. I set such a command in Rselenium, but chrome still keeps closing in cases where there is a long wait.

Any ideas how to prevent Rselenium from closing Chrome?

```
eCaps <- list(
chromeOptions = 
list(prefs = list("download.prompt_for_download" = FALSE,
                  "download.directory_upgrade" = TRUE,
                  "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally"= TRUE,
                  "download.default_directory" = URLFilesFolder,
                  "detach" = TRUE
 )
 )
 )

 rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", port = free_port(), chromever  = "latest", extraCapabilities = eCaps) 
 remDr <- rD$client
```